# Hosting a discord.js bot on Heroku

Tags: git, github, heroku, discord.js

I'm trying to store a discord bot on Heroku but I get an error when the app is running:

> Application error
>   An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
>   heroku logs --tail.

I don't know if I'm missing something or it's a bug.

This is the build log (I use GitHub to deploy):

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.16.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.13.4

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules is checked into source control and cannot be cached

-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules

       > nodemon@2.0.2 postinstall /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0

       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

       ascii-table@0.0.9 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ascii-table
       discord.js@12.0.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/discord.js
       @discordjs/collection@0.1.5 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/@discordjs/collection
       abort-controller@3.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/abort-controller
       event-target-shim@5.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/event-target-shim
       form-data@3.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/form-data
       asynckit@0.4.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/asynckit
       combined-stream@1.0.8 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/combined-stream
       delayed-stream@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/delayed-stream
       mime-types@2.1.26 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/mime-types
       mime-db@1.43.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/mime-db
       node-fetch@2.6.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/node-fetch
       prism-media@1.2.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/prism-media
       setimmediate@1.0.5 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/setimmediate
       tweetnacl@1.0.3 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/tweetnacl
       ws@7.2.3 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ws
       dotenv@8.2.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/dotenv
       fs@0.0.1-security /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/fs
       nodemon@2.0.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/nodemon
       chokidar@3.3.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/chokidar
       anymatch@3.1.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/anymatch
       normalize-path@3.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/normalize-path
       picomatch@2.2.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/picomatch
       braces@3.0.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/braces
       fill-range@7.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/fill-range
       to-regex-range@5.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/to-regex-range
       is-number@7.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-number
       glob-parent@5.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/glob-parent
       is-glob@4.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-glob
       is-extglob@2.1.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-extglob
       is-binary-path@2.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-binary-path
       binary-extensions@2.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/binary-extensions
       readdirp@3.3.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/readdirp
       debug@3.2.6 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/debug
       ms@2.1.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ms
       ignore-by-default@1.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ignore-by-default
       minimatch@3.0.4 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/minimatch
       brace-expansion@1.1.11 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/brace-expansion
       balanced-match@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/balanced-match
       concat-map@0.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/concat-map
       pstree.remy@1.1.7 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/pstree.remy
       semver@5.7.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/semver
       supports-color@5.5.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/supports-color
       has-flag@3.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/has-flag
       touch@3.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/touch
       nopt@1.0.10 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/nopt
       abbrev@1.1.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/abbrev
       undefsafe@2.0.3 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/undefsafe
       debug@2.6.9 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/undefsafe/node_modules/debug
       ms@2.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/undefsafe/node_modules/ms
       update-notifier@2.5.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/update-notifier
       boxen@1.3.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/boxen
       ansi-align@2.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ansi-align
       string-width@2.1.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/string-width
       is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point
       strip-ansi@4.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/strip-ansi
       ansi-regex@3.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ansi-regex
       camelcase@4.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/camelcase
       chalk@2.4.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/chalk
       ansi-styles@3.2.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ansi-styles
       color-convert@1.9.3 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/color-convert
       color-name@1.1.3 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/color-name
       escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/escape-string-regexp
       cli-boxes@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/cli-boxes
       term-size@1.2.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/term-size
       execa@0.7.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/execa
       cross-spawn@5.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/cross-spawn
       lru-cache@4.1.5 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/lru-cache
       pseudomap@1.0.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/pseudomap
       yallist@2.1.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/yallist
       shebang-command@1.2.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/shebang-command
       shebang-regex@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/shebang-regex
       which@1.3.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/which
       isexe@2.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/isexe
       get-stream@3.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/get-stream
       is-stream@1.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-stream
       npm-run-path@2.0.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/npm-run-path
       path-key@2.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/path-key
       p-finally@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/p-finally
       signal-exit@3.0.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/signal-exit
       strip-eof@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/strip-eof
       widest-line@2.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/widest-line
       configstore@3.1.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/configstore
       dot-prop@4.2.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/dot-prop
       is-obj@1.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-obj
       graceful-fs@4.2.3 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/graceful-fs
       make-dir@1.3.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/make-dir
       pify@3.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/pify
       unique-string@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/unique-string
       crypto-random-string@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/crypto-random-string
       write-file-atomic@2.4.3 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/write-file-atomic
       imurmurhash@0.1.4 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/imurmurhash
       xdg-basedir@3.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/xdg-basedir
       import-lazy@2.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/import-lazy
       is-ci@1.2.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-ci
       ci-info@1.6.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ci-info
       is-installed-globally@0.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-installed-globally
       global-dirs@0.1.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/global-dirs
       ini@1.3.5 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/ini
       is-path-inside@1.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-path-inside
       path-is-inside@1.0.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/path-is-inside
       is-npm@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-npm
       latest-version@3.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/latest-version
       package-json@4.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/package-json
       got@6.7.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/got
       create-error-class@3.0.2 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/create-error-class
       capture-stack-trace@1.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/capture-stack-trace
       duplexer3@0.1.4 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/duplexer3
       is-redirect@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-redirect
       is-retry-allowed@1.2.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/is-retry-allowed
       lowercase-keys@1.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/lowercase-keys
       safe-buffer@5.2.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/safe-buffer
       timed-out@4.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/timed-out
       unzip-response@2.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/unzip-response
       url-parse-lax@1.0.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/url-parse-lax
       prepend-http@1.0.4 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/prepend-http
       registry-auth-token@3.4.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/registry-auth-token
       rc@1.2.8 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/rc
       deep-extend@0.6.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/deep-extend
       minimist@1.2.5 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/minimist
       strip-json-comments@2.0.1 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/strip-json-comments
       registry-url@3.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/registry-url
       semver-diff@2.1.0 /tmp/build_317d5dd76ef85bfe907569c7873779e8/node_modules/semver-diff
       Installing any new modules (package.json)
       audited 159 packages in 1.2s

       1 package is looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build

-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 159 packages in 1.077s

       1 package is looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 23M
-----> Launching...
       Released v8
       https://super-discord-bot23.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Repository: https://github.com/yoavstrugo/Super-Bot.git

Comment: It seemed to *build* OK, where are the *run* logs?

Comment: I think there aren't any. It just didn't run

Comment: For us to be able to assist you, you need to provide the application server logs, because there is the reason for the crash. You get the runtime logs with `$ heroku logs -a super-discord-bot23` Your application is most likely crashing on boot, the build log is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open the app on Heroku. If the `web` dyno is disabled, and the `worker` one is enabled, then everything should be good. Check if your bot is online on Discord.

Do not click here :

[image]

Check if those are in the right position :

[image]